# What are the implications of a NASA Open Source Agreement version 1.3

Tags: software, open-source-software

There is [this code](https://github.com/nasa/NASTRAN-95) released under [*NASA Open Source Agreement version 1.3*](https://github.com/nasa/NASTRAN-95/raw/master/NASA%20Open%20Source%20Agreement-NASTRAN%2095.doc).

I don't get the license. Can I use the code in a commercial product? Any limitation?

Comment: tl;drLegal has a quick summary of the license terms: [NASA-1.3](https://tldrlegal.com/license/nasa-open-source-agreement-1.3-(nasa-1.3)). It is broadly similar to the GPL license, though with some special terms to account for the needs of US government agencies. While NASA-1.3 allows commercial use, its copyleft effect might be unattractive for commercial software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in a commercial product.  The 2 big restrictions are:

1. As with the GPL, a distributed copy or derivative must be distributed under the same licence.
2. Unlike the GPL, the limitation to contributions are that: "Each Contributor represents that its Modification is believed to be Contributor's original creation".  This means you cannot merge this with other products that you did not create, even if the licence of those products allows it.  This makes it largely incompatible with other FOS licences.

Comment: Thanks =) Just curious, how the 2nd restriction is implied? By which section of the license, I mean :)

Comment: Section 3.G.   I reference the exact text.